# RelativeLayout in Xamarin: Can't make a square

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've grabbed the sample project from here: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/BoxView/ListViewColors/

I'm trying to make visual changes, in particular I'm trying to get the color squares to be rounded circles. The color squares are `BoxView`s in the original, and they use `WidthRequest` and `HeighRequest`, both set to `50`. This succeeds in making them square. But:

1. `BoxView`s don't have a `CornerRadius` property, so I've made them `Frame`s instead.
2. I don't want to use points, I want to use `RelativeLayout` values, so I've tried to set both width and height using `Factor=0.1` of the `ItemTemplate`'s `Frame`.
3. It doesn't work! No matter what I do, the colored frames are just a weird oblong shape--they're not even square anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <ListView SeparatorVisibility="None"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              ItemsSource="{x:Static local:NamedColor.All}"
                  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Width,
                Factor=1}">
        <ListView.RowHeight>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
                <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="80" />
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="90" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ListView.RowHeight>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ContentView Padding="5">
                        <Frame x:Name="itemFrame"
                               BackgroundColor="#bbffffff"
                               Padding="8"
                               CornerRadius="10"
                               HasShadow="false">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Frame x:Name="colorFrame"
                                    CornerRadius="20"
                                    OutlineColor="Transparent"
                                    BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                                    HasShadow="false"
                                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=RelativeToView,
                                    ElementName=itemFrame,
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Factor=0.1}"
                                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
                                    Type=RelativeToView,
                                    ElementName=itemFrame,
                                    Property=Width,
                                    Factor=0.1}"/>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FriendlyName}"
                                           FontSize="22"
                                           VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding RgbDisplay, StringFormat='RGB = {0}'}"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ContentView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding in the outer frame seems to have interfered with the shape of your  circle, rendering it into an elliptical figure. Removing the padding works and you can obtain a circular shape from your frame.

The corner radius property for a frame usually doesn't render for UWP application. So, you'll need to make a custom renderer for your frame to obtain the circle. As for your listview you can use the following code:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <ContentView Padding="5">
                <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                     <Frame OutlineColor="Accent" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}" >
                         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}" >
                              <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" CornerRadius="60" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.6, Constant=0}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height,Factor=0.6,Constant=0}"/>
                              <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                   <Label Text="{Binding FriendlyName}" FontSize="22" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                                   <Label Text="{Binding RgbDisplay, StringFormat='RGB = {0}'}" FontSize="16" VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand" />
                              </StackLayout>
                         </StackLayout>
                     </Frame>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

For frame, custom renderer for UWP:

```
public class CustomFrame:FrameRenderer
{
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
     {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var frame = e.NewElement;
                Windows.UI.Color frameBG = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(
                    (byte)(frame.BackgroundColor.A * 255),
                    (byte)(frame.BackgroundColor.R * 255),
                    (byte)(frame.BackgroundColor.G * 255),
                    (byte)(frame.BackgroundColor.B * 255));

                Control.CornerRadius = new Windows.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(frame.CornerRadius);
                Control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(frameBG);
                frame.BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I guess I should have said I'm targeting mobile (iOS and Android) not UWP.

Comment: It should work on mobile device as well. Needless to say, it works on UWP. Just tried.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Aside from a lot of odd layout issues (the items no longer fill the width of the screen), the boxes are still oblong, and CornerRadius of 80 makes the frame disappear entirely. Am testing on iOS simulator tho.

Comment: I just fixed the code by removing the padding in the outer frame. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: OMG I just did the same exact thing. I was gonna post it as an answer but if you want to add it to your answer I'll give it to you.

Comment: Updated the answer with some more details.